# Js: variable gets overwritten on click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm stumped by this one, maybe you can help me out.

This is my html:

```
<ul class="wpsc_product_list_categories wpsc_product_list_categories_js">
<li><a href="#" id="products_all">All products</a></li>
<li><a href="#" class="wpsc_category_link "><span class="product_category_15">cat 1</span></a>
</li>
<li><a href="#" class="wpsc_category_link "><span class="product_category_12">cat 2</span></a></li>
</ul>
```

And here's my js:

```
jQuery(".wpsc_product_list_categories_js a").click( function() {    
    jQuery('.wpsc_product_list_categories a').removeClass('wpsc-current-cat');  
    jQuery(this).addClass('wpsc-current-cat');

    var className = jQuery(this).children().attr('class');

    jQuery('.products_list_product').fadeOut(300, function() { 
        jQuery('.products_list_product').removeClass('product_item_last');
        i = 2
        jQuery('.' + className).each(function(j){
            i = i + 1;
            if (i == 3) {
                jQuery(this).addClass('product_item_last'); 
                i = 0;
            }
        });
    });
    alert(className);
    jQuery('.' + className).fadeIn(300);
    return false;
});
```

The idea is when you click one of the links, the class of the span is stored in the variable 'className'. When you click it once, it works fine. When you click it a second time, the variable has suddenly changed to 'the_original_class_name' AND 'product_item_last'. This shouldn't happen, but I can't figure out why.

Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: I'm reading through you're code and I think we're going to need more of your HTML to reproduce your problem, as your fade is never run since  `.products_list_product` doesn't exist.

Comment: This is the page in action: http://badlands777.com/shop. If you click the product selector links more then once, the products don't fade in any more.

Answer (score 2):

You're using `this` inside a function, but you are trying to refer to `this` in another scope.

```
jQuery(".wpsc_product_list_categories_js a").click( function() {    
    jQuery('.wpsc_product_list_categories a').removeClass('wpsc-current-cat');  
    jQuery(this).addClass('wpsc-current-cat');

    var className = jQuery(this).children().attr('class');

    jQuery('.products_list_product').fadeOut(300, function() { 
        jQuery('.products_list_product').removeClass('product_item_last');
        var $this = $(this);      //this is the "this" that you want(i think)!!!!
        i = 2
        jQuery('.' + className).each(function(j){
            i = i + 1;
            if (i == 3) {
                $this.addClass('product_item_last');  //and use it here!!!!!
                i = 0;
            }
        });
    });
    alert(className);
    jQuery('.' + className).fadeIn(300);
    return false;
});​
```

[image]

Comment: Ha, thanks for that picture. Ok, maybe it's easier to look at the actual page. It's over here: badlands777.com/shop. If you click the product selector links more then once, the products don't fade in any more, which is due to the fact that the className variable changes after you select a product category.

Comment: Ya, the fix I posted works when I edit the javascript on your page. You also need to modify `jQuery("#products_all").click( function() {` in the same way.